# REST PUT + idempotency. How does the client provide a valid ID?

Tags: rest, put

I know that `PUT` should be idempotent, and the client should define the ID for the object to create. But there is something I don't clearly understand: how does the client get an available ID? Should be there an other web service that provides one? Is there a best practice for this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

client should first `GET` the Resource Representation

then issue `PUT` with changes along with the `id` from above step

It is also recommended to use `If-Modified` tags to avoid a conflict

Comment: I guess by 'Resource Representation' you mean the metadata. I still don't see how this can provide an id for the new entity.

Comment: if its a new entity you need to use `POST` , the `id` creation logic should be server side (service end) not client.

Comment: 1. What is "tag"?
2. If you meant http header, there's no such header "If-Modified'.